# WP custom rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

I've got URL: 
http://example.com/alternatywy/?id=getresponse

And I'm trying to rewrite it to:
http://example.com/alternatywy/getresponse

I've added to my functions.php:

```
add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_tags');
function dcc_rewrite_tags() {
    add_rewrite_tag('%id%', '([^&]+)');
}

add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_rules');
function dcc_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^alternatywy/(.+)/?$','index.php?page_id=8286&id=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is this question tagged `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
add_filter('query_vars', function($vars) {
    $vars[] = "id";
    return $vars;
});

add_action('init', 'dcc_rewrite_rules');
function dcc_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^alternatywy/([^/]+)/?$','index.php?page_id=8286&id=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

Now its time to flush rewrite rules. You can do it within two ways either by code or by manual save permalink.

Manual:

> From WordPress Administration Screens, Select Settings -> Permalinks
>   and just click Save Changes without any changes.

Code:

```
/* Flush rewrite rules for custom post types. */
add_action( 'after_switch_theme', 'flush_rewrite_rules' );
```

Comment: It's not working. Even if i'm going to http://example.com/index.php?page_id=8286&id=getresponse it redirects me to http://example.com/alternatywy/?id=getresponse :(

Comment: What is your permalink structure? Did you flush the permalink?